# Result when the sum value is '8' should be even, yet it says odd [Update : the 'else' branch seems not working, when the sum is odd, it's nt wrkg]

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean-logic

I've been looking at the code that I've written for few hours. I tried looking at other people's solution, compare and applied to my code but still my code doesn't work as it supposed to. I tried checking on the indentation, changing the `name2.equals()` with `name2.equalsIgnoreCase()`, still my code doesn't work as I expect. Can you please have a look at my code?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OddsAndEvens {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Let's play a game called \"Odds and Evens\"");
        System.out.println("What is your name? ");
        String name = input.next();
        System.out.println("Hi "+name+", which do you choose? (O)dds or (E)vens?");
        String name2 = input.next();

        if (name2.equals("O")) {
            System.out.println(name+" has picked "+name2+"! The computer will be evens.");
        } else if (name2.equals("E")) {
            System.out.println(name+" has picked "+name2+"! The computer will be odds.");
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("Please pick either odds or evens!");
        }
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("How many \"fingers\" do you put out?");
        int userNumber = input.nextInt();

        Random rand = new Random();
        int computer = rand.nextInt(6);
        System.out.println("The computer plays number "+computer);
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
        int sum = computer + userNumber;
        System.out.println("The sum is "+ sum);

        boolean oddOrEven = sum % 2 == 0;

        if (oddOrEven) {
            if (name2.equals("E")) {
                System.out.println(sum+" is even..!");
                System.out.println(name+" wins!");
            } else if (name2.equals("O")) {
                System.out.println(sum+" is odd..!");
                System.out.println("The computer wins!");
            }
        else {
                System.out.println(sum+" is odd..!");
                if (name2.equals("E")) {
                    System.out.println("The computer wins!");
                } else if (name2.equals("O")) {
                    System.out.println(name+" wins!");
                 }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: The true branch of `if (oddOrEven) {` has both `sum+" is even"` and `sum+" is odd"` in it which can't be right. You got the nested ifs mixed up somewhat.

Comment: Also, some of your variable names are at least confusing. The variable `oddOrEven` is `true` if `sum` is *even*, so it should be renamed to something like `sumIsEven`.

Comment: Your alignment is still crappy. Take a close look at to what branch your `else` block belongs.

Comment: Life advise: Use your IDEs "auto-format" feature, then those things will not happen to you anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Take a close look at your indentation:

```java
if (oddOrEven) {
    if (name2.equals("E")) {
        System.out.println(sum+" is even..!");
        System.out.println(name+" wins!");
    }
else if (name2.equals("O")) {
        System.out.println(sum+" is odd..!");
        System.out.println("The computer wins!");
    }
else {
        System.out.println(sum+" is odd..!");
        if (name2.equals("E")) {
            System.out.println("The computer wins!");
        } else if (name2.equals("O")) {
            System.out.println(name+" wins!");
            }
    }
}
```

If we reindent it correctly, [the] problem becomes more apparent:

```java
if (oddOrEven) {
    if (name2.equals("E")) {
        System.out.println(sum+" is even..!");
        System.out.println(name+" wins!");
    }
    else if (name2.equals("O")) {
        System.out.println(sum+" is odd..!");
        System.out.println("The computer wins!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(sum+" is odd..!");
        if (name2.equals("E")) {
            System.out.println("The computer wins!");
        }
        else if (name2.equals("O")) {
            System.out.println(name+" wins!");
        }
    }
}
```

The `else` branch is only executed when `name2` is neither `E` or `O`. Then within the `else` branch, it is stated that `sum` is odd, but the parent `if`-statement, which is `if (oddOrEven)`, is true when the sum is even. Then `name2` is again compared to `E` and `O`, but that has already been done.

This is all very confusing. You should stop writing one long method, where stuff can get confusing easily, but instead utilizing *methods*.

For instance, you could create a method, which accept both the computer input and the user input, and return `true` if the sum is even:

```java
public static boolean isEven(int userInput, int computerInput) {
    int sum = userInput + computerInput;
    boolean sumIsEven = sum % 2 == 0;
    return sumIsEven;
}
```

Then you could create another method which accepts the selected *parity* (odd or even) and *user input*, which then returns whether the user wins. It could also utilize the abovementioned method:

```java
// Capture the selected parity and set the boolean to the corresponding
// value.
// If the user enters neither 'E' or 'O', the program should not continue,
// instead, the user should be asked again to enter a correct parity.
boolean userSelectedParityIsEven = ...;

Random r = new Random();
int computer = rand.nextInt(6);
// Capture user-provided number here.
int userInput = ...;

boolean sumIsEven = isEven(userInput, computer);
if (sumIsEven) {
    System.out.println("The sum is even!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("The sum is odd!");
}

boolean match = (sumIsEven == userSelectedParityIsEven);
if (match) {
    System.out.println(name + " wins!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("The computer wins!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problems when evaluating the outcome of the game.

**Indentation and curly braces**

First of all, your placement of curly braces in the whole `if` construct is faulty. This means that your `else` block belongs (if properly formatted) to the inner `if (name2.equals("E"))` clause. (The other answer goes into more detail here, therefore I won't elaborate this issue further)

To fix this, add a closing curly brace before the `else` and remove one at the end of the whole outer `if` clause.

**Printing incorrect output**

Furthermore you have an issue in your `if` block here:

```java
if (oddOrEven) {
    ...
}
```

The `...` is the code that is executed in case the outcome of the game is "*even*". (You should definitely rename your `boolean`, e.g. to `isEven`, because you are only confusing yourself with the current variable name)

So in detail, the issue is commented in the following snippet:

```java
if (name2.equals("E")) {
    System.out.println(sum+" is even..!");
    System.out.println(name+" wins!");
} else if (name2.equals("O")) {
    System.out.println(sum+" is odd..!"); // <--- this is incorrect
    System.out.println("The computer wins!");
}
```

So you are actually doing the right thing, but your output is incorrect.
Update this snippet according to the logic in your `else`:

```java
System.out.println(sum+" is even..!");
if (name2.equals("E")) {
    System.out.println(name+" wins!");
} else if (name2.equals("O")) {
    System.out.println("The computer wins!");
}
```

**Conclusion**

Summing all suggestions in one snippet:

```java
if (isEven) {
    System.out.println(sum + " is even..!");
    if (name2.equals("E")) {
        System.out.println(name + " wins!");
    } else if (name2.equals("O")) {
        System.out.println("The computer wins!");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println(sum + " is odd..!");
    if (name2.equals("E")) {
        System.out.println("The computer wins!");
    } else if (name2.equals("O")) {
        System.out.println(name + " wins!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggested solution. I've applied this to my code. It's working well but there seems to be a problem that when the added number is odd. The 'else' branch seems to not be executed. I can't figure out the solution.

Comment: @JabriJuhinin in this case, please feel free to ask a new question, with your updated code and problem description.